# How do I get code coverage report?

Tags: htmlunit

I'm using HTML unit test for presentation tier testing , is there any mechanism/framework available to find code coverage report?

Comment: You want coverage data on what HTML page/tag/actions have been executed?  Or you want coverage on the dynamic scripts that run most pages?

Comment: I want a coverage on HTML elements in each page/each JSP.